# Abelian Groups and Number Theory

Tags: group-theory

What is the connection between "Finite Abelian Groups" and "Chinese Remainder Theorem"?

---

(I have not seen the "abstract theory" behind Chinese Remainder Theorem and also its proof. On the other hand, I know abstract group theory and classification of finite abelian  groups. Please, give also a motivation to study "Chinese Remainder Theorem from "Group Theory point of view".)

Comment: The abelian-group-theoretic statement of Sun-Ze (aka CRT) is $$n=\prod_pp^{e_p}\implies \frac{\Bbb Z}{n{\Bbb Z}}\cong\prod_p\frac{\Bbb Z}{p^{e_p}{\Bbb Z}}.$$ This is on Wikipedia's CRT article too. And that's that.

Comment: @anon: The statement you made is possibly connection between "Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic" and "Group Theory", isn't it?

Comment: The statement I made is called the chinese remainder theorem.

Comment: I mean, left side in your statement is fundamental theorem of arithmatic. Right side is a group theoretic statement; what is connection of RHS with "Chinese Remainder Theorem(in older, purely number theoretic version)"

Comment: The left side is not even a statement. The fact that any integer can be written in that form (and thus that the formula will always be useful) is the fundamental theorem.

Comment: I would think that the abstract algebra view to CRT works at the level commutative rings. If $R$ is a ring and $I_1,I_2$ are ideals with the property $I_1+I_2=R$, then (a generalized version of) CRT states that
$$R/(I_1\cap I_2)\simeq (R/I_1)\oplus (R/I_2).$$ This formulation covers both the integer congruence version as well as facts like: knowing a polynomial with real coefficients modulo $x^2-1$ is the same as knowing it modulo both $x-1$ and $x+1$. Comes in handy, when you really have to justify (while studying integration of rational functions) that partial fraction decompositions exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $m$ and $n$ be coprime, and let $a$ and $b$ be any integers. According to the Chinese remainder theorem, there exists a unique solution modulo $mn$ to the pair of equations

$$x \equiv a \mod{m}$$
$$x \equiv b \mod{n}$$

Now the map $(a,b) \mapsto x$ is an isomorphism of rings from $\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ to $\mathbb{Z}/mn\mathbb{Z}$.

Conversely, if we are given an isomorphism of rings $\phi: \mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}/mn\mathbb{Z}$, then $x = \phi(a,b)$ is a solution to the pair of equations since in this case $\phi(x,x) = x = \phi(a,b)$.

Comment: nice answer. Suppose $m,n$ are not relatively prime. Then does solution to above two congruence equations does not exist or the solution is not multiple of $mn$?

Comment: A solution exists if and only if $a \equiv b \mod{d}$, where $d = \gcd(m,n)$. For example, $x \equiv 1 \mod{2}$, $x \equiv 2 \mod{4}$ has no solution. If a solution exists, it is unique modulo $\operatorname{lcm}(m,n)$.